# Parameter args of method main never used

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I've installed `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers`, `Roslynator.Analyzers`, `SonarAnalyzer.CSharp`, `StyleCop.Analyzers` to help me write better code in C#, but I get an error whenever I write code, even if it`s 1 line. The error says:

> "Parameter args of method main never used"

How can I fix it and why do I get the error?

[image]

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine(n);


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Get rid of the args parameter in Main if you don't intend to use it. The args parameter contains any arguments passed to your program when run on the command line. By default, it contains just one value - the name of your program.

Comment: Just change `Main(string[] args)` to `Main()`. See [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/main-and-command-args/).

Comment: The error message **continues**: _“Remove the parameter or use it in the method body.”_ What's the point of installing four (!) different code analyzers if you can't follow their advice?

Comment: Hi John, If you feel an answer helped you to solve your question, please don't forget to mark it as accepted by clicking the gray check mark beside the answer. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 4):

The parameters are optional in the main method and can be removed if you don't need to use command line arguments.

This code is also valid:

```
internal static Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        // 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually since you didn't use the args parameter in your method, you can safely remove it. But FYI, you can pass some args to this method that could be sometimes helpful,
by right clicking on the project you are working on and choosing the properties, then by going to the Debug tab and then, on the Start Options section provide the app with your args, just like the following image:

[image]

Comment: I'm really curious to find out what's the reason of the downvote. If I am wrong I would like to fix my answer! Can you please let me know what's wrong with that!?

Answer (score 0):

You don't use the `args` parameter in `Main`. 
Remove it if you will not use it further.

Code:

```
static void Main()
{
    int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine(n);
}
```